# Redirect to Search URL

Tags: html

I want the input of a users search to redirect them to the URL example.com/plans?input

How do I create a button that does that? So far I have the following but it does nothing upon hitting enter.

```
" onsearch="javascript:alert('http://www.example.com/plans?' + this.value);"/></input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is creating a form:

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/plans" method="GET">
   <input type="text" name="query"/>
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When the submit button is clicked, the data will be sent to:

```
http://www.example.com/plans?query=thequery
```